# How to combine two audio files into one in Android

Tags: android, audio

I want to combine two audio files. (A audio file + B audio file = AB audio file)

After searching around, I think the following steps will work

1. Using an AudioTrack.
2. Decode PCM from audio files.
3. Combine PCM.

Are the above steps right, if not, what would be another way to achieve it?

Is there an example and Library source available to look at?

Comment: Hi i need combine two audio as you a + b = ab. i am using media recorder. How do you combine? please help me.

Comment: Have you found the solution for your question ? please tell me, I also have same query.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check [Audio Development for Android](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f2/play-audio-using-sound-package-24234/) for information on the subject.  Its going to take some research, I do not know much about Android or I would help further.

Comment: Can you explain how the above link helped solved the problem? I don't see anywhere on that link where they describe combining audio files. Also I don't see why people link to solutions on here. Unless it's a ton of code, just put the code on this site (or at least pseudo code, overview etc). Links are subject to breaking etc, and stack overflow is pretty much the best source of information for development.

Comment: @Jimmie Clark I don't know why you accept this answer

Comment: hi i am also facing same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908724/how-to-mix-two-pcm-streams-into-single-mp4-file

Comment: Please help me, i have same problem and above answer is not able to solve my problem.

Comment: I think this thread should be closed because it is unhelpful. Or maybe a cheat thread to get points.