# Android : merge two audio files into one file

Tags: android

I am working in Android. I want to merge two audio files and want to create a third audio file. suppose I have A and B audio file then after merge I want to have a file AB.

I have googled it so many times, searched every where but I could not get any positive response. I really really need help now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some useful links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844514/how-combine-only-one-audio-file-from-two-audio-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191408/mixing-audio-files

I hope it helps you.

Comment: @FranVerona I already visited those links but there is not good solution for that... thank you...
please help me to get some more ideas...